# What do you call the place where car tires are changed, oil is checked and if there is something wrong with your car, it is fixed?

Tags: word-choice

What do you call the place where car tires are changed, oil is checked and if there is something wrong with your car, it is fixed there? I would like to know what people call that plece in American and British English.

Comment: In UK there isn't just *one* place. There are workshops that specialise in tyres, brakes, batteries and exhausts, and some of those will also do simple maintenance and regular services. These are sometimes called a **tyre shop** or **tyre depot**, and service is often "on demand" or "while you wait" with no booking system. The more skilled **garages** and **service centres** can do those jobs as well as more advanced repairs, and you usually need an advance booking.

Comment: There isn't really a special place; it's what regular car mechanics (auto mechanics) do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The umbrella term for all the various types of specialist places you might take your car to for repair is a "*garage*".

> My car is in the garage.

Yes, the outhouse on a home where you may store a car is also called a garage - it is all about context. *I'm going to the store* is always understood as being the place where you buy things when you use it in context, even though the word "store" can mean other things.

As has been mentioned in comments, there are specialist garages that deal with specific aspects of car repairs. In the UK, a garage that fixes dents and bumps in the exterior body is called either a *body shop*, or a *coachworks*, but these are still types of *garage*.

Comment: This is UK-specific; in the U.S. we more often say a car is in the **shop**.

Comment: @TypeIA In the US, it would be a regional preference. Locally here in the mid-Atlantic, you hear garage more if we're talking maintenance, shop if you need body work.